# TFS not adding files to repository properly

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs, ssis

We are working with building ETL packages in SSIS using a TFS repository. When my collegue add new files to the repository they are not added properly to the repository even though he checks in the entire project file. He sees the files in his project folder, and it looks like everything is checked in. But when I click on "Get latest version" I get a warning that the package is missing from the project directory. If any of us then try to add the file again we get a warning that the file all redy exists, even though it is not visible in my folders. Right now the solution we are using is for him to delete the file and then commit the change. After he deletes the file I get the latest version. Then he sends me the files and then I add them to the repository. Once I have added the files things seem to work as expected. Has anyone else had this problem, and know of a solution?

UPDATE:

The solution we found now is that I have to go to the local folder and find the new file my colegue added. Then I right click the file he just added and select add to project. Then the new file is visible in my version, but it does not have a blue lock icon next to it. If I then double click the sln-file to reload the project the blue lock icon is visible to me.

It is still not an optimal solution, but it works a lot better than him having to send me the file so I could check it in.

Is this the way TFS is supposed to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please check the mapped work space path in your local machine there you will find the checked code. You need to manually Add.

Right Click on SSIS package -->AddExisting Package--> Select the package from Workspace-->Ok

Now you will find the missing package in your Solution Explorer as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using TFVC.

1. Open Source Control Explorer=>Right click that solution/project folder=>View History, then check the related ChangeSet whether he add the file correctly.
2. Let your college to check the permission of that folder/file: Right click the folder/file->Advanced=>Security.

Regards